# Unable to locate iframe with javascript src in selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, iframe

I have an `iframe` in my html code which has javascript source. I am not able to locate the `iframe`.

Html for `iframe` is-

```
<table id="page_content_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; height: 36em;">

<tbody>

<tr class="mceFirst" role="presentation"></tr>

<tr>

<td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">

<iframe id="page_content_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 36em; display: block;"/>

</td>

</tr>

<tr class="mceLast"></tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

My selenium Webdriver code is-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("page_content_ifr"))));

        driver.switchTo().frame("page_content_ifr");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//p[br[@data-mce-bogus='1']]"))));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[br[@data-mce-bogus='1']]")).sendKeys("New Page Heading");

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is the error you get ? You gave very few information about your problem.

Comment: <table id="page_content_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; height: 36em;">

<tbody>

<tr class="mceFirst" role="presentation"></tr>

<tr>

<td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">

<iframe id="page_content_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 36em; display: block;"/>

</td>

</tr>

<tr class="mceLast"></tr>

</tbody>

</table>

Comment: It is throwing unable to find element